# Egressgateway enable to see the requests in the log

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I am following the istio 1.6 [documentation example](https://istio.io/v1.6/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic).

I have deployed a ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: cnn
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```

The Gateway and destination rule:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - edition.cnn.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-cnn
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: cnn
```

and the VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-cnn-through-egress-gateway
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: cnn
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
```

Everything like it is in the tutorial, then I ran:

```
 kubectl exec -it $SOURCE_POD -c sleep -- curl -sL -o /dev/null -D - http://edition.cnn.com/politics
```

However, in step 6:

```
Check the log of the istio-egressgateway pod for a line corresponding to our request. If Istio is deployed in the istio-system namespace, the command to print the log is:

$ kubectl logs -l istio=egressgateway -c istio-proxy -n istio-system | tail

You should see a line similar to the following:

[2019-09-03T20:57:49.103Z] "GET /politics HTTP/2" 301 - "-" "-" 0 0 90 89 "10.244.2.10" "curl/7.64.0" "ea379962-9b5c-4431-ab66-f01994f5a5a5" "edition.cnn.com" "151.101.65.67:80" outbound|80||edition.cnn.com - 10.244.1.5:80 10.244.2.10:50482 edition.cnn.com -
```

I cannot see anything in my logs, it looks like the traffic is not getting passed by the egressgateway. What am I doing wrong, I am basically following the same steps as the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue.
It seems you skipped the [Enable Envoy’s access logging](https://istio.io/v1.6/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging) mentioned in **Before you begin** section.

what you need to do is to issue the command

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo --set meshConfig.accessLogFile="/dev/stdout"
```

then send the request again

```
kubectl exec -it $SOURCE_POD -c sleep -- curl -sL -o /dev/null -D - https://edition.cnn.com/politics
```

and check the logs

```
kubectl logs -l istio=egressgateway -n istio-system
```

after doing all that, I see in my logs

```
...
[2021-05-14T05:51:41.940Z] "GET /politics HTTP/2" 301 - "-" "-" 0 0 23 22 "10.4.2.6" "curl/7.69.1" "fc2903d6-904c-91ce-bfde-24f395db67eb" "edition.cnn.com" "151.101.65.67:80" outbound|80||edition.cnn.com 10.4.0.10:57078 10.4.0.10:8080 10.4.2.6:36238 - -
```

Answer (score 1):

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoys-access-logging

Istio offers a few ways to enable access logs. Use of the Telemetry API is recommended.

```
$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: mesh-default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  accessLogging:
    - providers:
      - name: envoy
EOF
```

Or using Mesh Config:

```
$ istioctl install <flags-you-used-to-install-Istio> --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout
```

This is a part of my istio mesh config:

```
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    outboundTrafficPolicy:
      mode: REGISTRY_ONLY
  profile: demo
  tag: 1.17.1
```